# Why does Skype now show up as Skype[3]

Tags: skype, icons

The Skype icon on my task bar shows up with the S logo and a number 3 in it in gold. Does it mean 3 copies of Skype are open or that I am using version 3 of Skype? I only want to run 1 copy of Skype at a time.

Comment: Skype only allows a single instance of itself.

Comment: what OS are you using?  If you are in Windows, hover over the icon and see if 3 previews show up, if only 1 shows up, only 1 is running.  If you updated recently it could be that program created a new shortcut and didn't delete the old one first.  As far as I know Skype is on version 7+.

Comment: A screenshot would make this question far more interesting.

Comment: Just dawned on me that you may have 3 new messages or contact requests or something.

Comment: -1: Simply Googling "Skype Icon Number" provides the answer multiple times.. http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-archive/Small-Number-in-Skype-icon/td-p/705581, http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-archive/Number-1-on-yellow-background-on-skype-program-icon/td-p/1310868, http://community.skype.com/t5/iOS-archive/Little-orange-number-one/td-p/3483839, etc.

Answer (score 3):

It's not the version number but the count of unread messages you have:

[image]

To get rid of it, open Skype and click on Recent -> Mark all viewed